# How to get object at given x,y position by calling 'elementFromPoint' JavaScript command

Tags: javascript, c#, google-chrome-devtools

I'm using `Chrome DevTools` library for `C#`. I would like to use it to call `JavaScript` commands, namely `elementFromPoint()` command to get object from a given position. How can I do it?

Comment: What library are you using? You need to connect to a web socket using the [Remote Debugging Protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/debugger-protocol-viewer/1-2/). The library will likely expose a function that calls [`Runtime.evaluate`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/debugger-protocol-viewer/1-2/Runtime/#method-evaluate), which will evaluate JavaScript expressions on the page.

Comment: Hi. It was actually what i was looking for. I'm using two projects to check it (https://github.com/MasterDevs/ChromeDevTools and https://github.com/martinkunc/automate-chrome). In one there are some errors, but finally i managed to get the results. Thank You for Your time.